# SharePoint Workflow - Check status across multiple list items and update list item

Tags: list, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow

Looking for some help on solving a problem in using SharePoint workflows. (i'm using SharePoint 2010 & designer 2010)  I'm pretty new to SharePoint and I've been reading over the following link info: [SharePoint Workflow QuickReference](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Workflow-actions-in-SharePoint-Designer-2010-A-quick-reference-guide-5a7ad276-0ed7-49b0-b652-e56a77dd96c6) & [How to loop using workflow](http://blog.rbaconsulting.com/tutorial-how-to-loop-through-multiple-list-items-without-code-using-a-sharepoint-2010-workflow/).  The second link sparked some ideas which I'll be testing tomorrow.

What I want to do:
I want to be able to have a workflow review a custom list with multiple items, which can have the same item e.g name_ID.  For all list item w/ that name_ID check to see the status and update another custom list with that name_ID.  Make sense?

SharePoint Lists:
List 1:  Master List (tasker)
List 2:  Sub List (tasks)

List 1 Columns:
Tasker No. | Tasker Description | Tasker Status

List 2 Columns:
Tasker No. | Sub ID | Task Description | task status

List 1 (Master Tasker) is the parent tasker that has multiple List 2 (Sub List) sub tasks that need to complete before the Master Tasker status can complete.  I'd like the workflow to look at List 2, find all Tasker No. that match the List 1 Tasker No. and check the status of each sub task in List 2.  Based on the status in list 2 for all sub task, update the status in List 1.

Additional example:

List 1:

0023 |  Tasker A | Select One (this is just the default value)

0024 |  Tasker B | Select One

List 2:

0023 | 3.A.1 | subtask A | In process

0023 | 3.A.2 | subtask A | Completed

0024 | 3.B.1 | subtask B | Completed

Workflow runs and see that 0023 in List 2 has sub task of "in process" and "completed.  It would then update list 1 "0023" to a status of "in process".  It would also see "0024" in list 2 as "completed" and updates list 1 "0024" to status as "completed".

Any help is appreciated.  I'll keep asking question and updating as i work through it..

Answer (score 0):

I've moved this question to the SharePoint forum for Stack in effort to get more attention / assistance: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/144874/sharepoint-workflow-check-status-across-multiple-list-items-and-update-list-it